# Is possible to change the default MongoDB UTC date format in Database Server

Tags: mongodb

By Default the mongodb stores the time in default UTC format [Mongo Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-time-data/#example) 
  while executing

```
new Date() //ISODate("2016-10-05T07:54:21.525Z")
```

I want the result in IST  timezone

If there is any settings to change into **IST** or any other timezone

Comment: You have also one solution sugested in the link you have provided - `Applications that must operate or report on some unmodified local time value may store the time zone alongside the UTC timestamp, and compute the original local time in their application logic.`

Comment: If there is any way to change the thing in default mongodb server

Comment: Technically you can mess with the underlining server and changed it's timezone in such a way that reflects in MongoDB, but this is not the recommended way to build applications

Comment: Actually you can store the timezone in the timestamp format since it is ISO compliant but MongoDB will not apply the timezone on it's side

Answer (score 0):

**NO**, you can not change mongodb timezone format from UTC to IST.

What you can do is just create a function/middleware to convert UTC to IST and use this module wherever you need to display time in IST.

Comment: In system.profile and log files mongodb create time in UTC so I am not able to write any middleware  to change those things. So that only am asking any other settings in mongodb any way thanks for your reply

Comment: yes.. even in this case there is no alternate way according to me because same conditions i was in previous 4 weeks ago...